# Why does os.open produce PermissionError even though os.R_OK is true?

Tags: python

I have a function that is supposed to loop through all the files in a folder and open them in `"rb"` so they can be used in conjunction with `hashlib.md5()`.  I was getting permission exceptions so I added an if statement intended to skip over those that I don't have read access to (`os.R_OK`).  It reduced the errors, but I am still running into some files that produce permission exceptions.

I found a website that stated: I/O operations may fail even when `access()` indicates that they would succeed, particularly for operations on network filesystems which may have permissions semantics beyond the usual POSIX permission-bit model.

But it didn't give any answer to this problem.

Is there any way to get around this so my function will skip over the files it cannot open?

```
def hashfile(path, blocksize = 65536):
    if os.access(path,os.R_OK):
        afile = open(path, "rb")
        hasher = hashlib.md5()
        buf = afile.read(blocksize)
        while len(buf) > 0:
            hasher.update(buf)
            buf = afile.read(blocksize)
        afile.close()
        return hasher.hexdigest()
```

Comment: What about using a `try`-`except` block to skip over such files?

Comment: The website which states what access does is the [official python documentation for `os.access`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.html#os.access). It does explain your problem. The same doc says _"It’s preferable to use [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3.7/glossary.html#term-eafp) techniques"_, i.e. a `try`/`except` block, as @iz_ suggested.

Comment: IN other words forget about testing with `os.access()` first, just `try` to open the files and handle it in the `except` clause when it doesn't work. "Handling" it include just ignoring it with a `pass` statement and/or printing or logging what happened.

Comment: It looks like the try/except block worked.  Thank you everyone for your help.